# CountDownTimer won't stop

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, timer

please i am a beginner at android and i'm trying to add a CountDownTimer to my quizz , well the CountDownTimer works well and when i answer all questions in the time limit i get my results like this :
Corrects Answers : 14
Wrong Answers : 16
Score : 14/30

In case i don't catch time i get something like this : 
Corrects Answers : 14
Wrong Answers : 0
Score : 14/30

Which is correct in my opinions because in that case answers are not wrong but unanswered

But if it happens that i answer all questions before the time finishes .I get the results as i want but the Count doesn't stop and keeps on running until 0 and on 0 it shows that afterward :
Corrects Answers : 0
Wrong Answers : 0
Score : 0/30

Here is the code for the timer :

mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {

```
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             textViewtimer.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {                
             marks = (correct+wrong)-wrong;              
                Intent resultintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(resultintent);
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
         }
          }.start();
```

Though i'm calling the Intent part somewhere else too to lead me to the score page 
Please can anyone give me a hint or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic on implementing `onFinish` is wrong. `onFinish` getting called **after** your timer has been done **or** you called `cancel`.

You should move the `mCountDownTimer.cancel();` to the last question (probably), and it will call `onFinish` automatically.

In your current code, your timer will be canceled **only** if the timer has been done, because you called `cancel` in the `onFinish`.

Comment: Thank you sir i as you said exactly just moved mCountDownTimer.cancel to last question and it appears that it works fine now . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

please use following code.

```
// Global variable. Put
private boolean isRunning = true;

while(isRunning)
{
    textViewtimer.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    if((millisUntilFinished / 1000) <= 0)
        isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code but i just moved the mCountDownTimer.cancel to my last question as Blaze Tama suggested and now it works fine but thank you very much i'll keep this code u gave me  too